# Application asks for internet connection

Tags: python, symbian, nokia, pys60

When I start any application, that I wrote with python for my Nokia 5800(software version 60.0.003), it asks me for internet connection. Application doesn't use it or need it. And if I skip it applications works fine.

I'm using ensymble(PyS60 application packager 2.0.0) with Python 2.5.2 to create application, and python version 2.0.0 on Nokia phone.

I tried to put just "--caps=" or "--caps=ReadUserData" to check if this will remove it, but it still asks for access point. Even for simple application as:

```
print "Hello world!"
```

Does somebody knows how can I remove this?

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe this should go on ServerFault.  What interpreter does it use?

Comment: TMHO I do think it's a problem related to programming and then SO is ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not Python itself. I've traced it and it doesn't open any sockets when starting up. Check the capabilities that are set on the Python interpreter. Maybe it has the NetworkServices capability set because it *can* use sockets.